# Emacs: open file in new window in vertical split

Tags: emacs

I'm new to Emacs.

When using Emacs to write text, I often have one window open in a frame.

When I want to open a *second* file in a new window within the frame, I want to *vertically split the frame and open a new window at right* (not split horizontally and open at bottom, etc.) How do I do that?

I know that `C-x 3` opens a new vertically split buffer window at right, and `C-x 4 f` opens a file at bottom (a horizontal split). That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Most users try and use functions such as `find-file-other-window`; `split-window-vertically`; `split-window-horizontally`; `other-window`; `select-window`; etc.  If you are like me and wish to take complete control of how to split along with the size, here is a link to an example that uses the internal window splitting function `window--display-buffer`:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26970/2287  Essentially, we can use `find-file-noselect` and then display the buffer wherever and however we want ....

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to do this, but this works:

```lisp
(defun find-file-other-window-vertically nil
  "Edit a file in another window, split vertically."
  (interactive)
  (let ((split-width-threshold 0)
        (split-height-threshold nil))
    (call-interactively 'find-file-other-window)))
```